# Launch Android DeskClock ScreensaverActivity

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way to launch this app directly?

The DeskClock app (from source code) launches this by doing:

```
case R.id.menu_item_night_mode:
                    startActivity(new Intent(DeskClock.this, ScreensaverActivity.class));
```

I've tried, but with no luck:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.ScreensaverActivity"));
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That Activity doesn't seem to be exported, I doubt you could do this.